# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in (click) for mat-chip

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when trying to set a value on a click event for a mat-chip

I'm created a stackblitz to see the error in action (Open the console then click two or more chips): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddapw1?file=app/chips-stacked-example.html

```
// index.html
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let chip of availableItems; index as idx"
      [selected]="selectedItems.indexOf(idx) > -1"
      (click)="select(idx)">
    {{chip}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>

// index.js
import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'chips-stacked-example',
  templateUrl: 'chips-stacked-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['chips-stacked-example.css'],
})
export class ChipsStackedExample {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  availableItems = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  selectedItems = [];
  select(idx) {
    console.log('selecting', idx);
    this.selectedItems.push(idx);
    //this.cdr.detectChanges()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to add the `multiple` attribute:

```
<mat-chip-list multiple>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution, I filed a bug to fix this non-intuitive behavior: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20548

Comment: Thank you! Surely angular material can throw a better error than that ...